# get div element defined from a scriptlet using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page that contains a scriptlet like

```
    <div id="flash_chart">
    <%=content_data['report_text']%>
    </div>
```

The variable `content_data['report_text']` holds a long string which is actually some html and javascript code, shown as following

```
    <div id='Fusion_12345678'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script class="fusioncharts" type='text/javascript'>
    if(!document.getElementById('id_chart_Fusion_1779126')){
    if(typeof(printRequest) === 'function') printRequest();
        window.chart_Fusion_1779126 = FusionCharts.render({
    swfUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/mysentry/assets/ireportpro      
    id: 'id_chart_Fusion_1779126',
    width: '100%',
    height: '450',
    debugMode: 0,
    registerWithJS: 1,
    renderAt: 'Fusion_1779126',
            ...
    </script>
```

On my web page, I tried to use `document.getElementById('Fusion_12345678')` to get the div defined from the scriptlet, but it does not work. Anybody knows how can I get that div 'Fusion-12345678' using javascript? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there something in the div? Your example above has it empty.

Comment: How does getElementById not work? Are you using jquery?

Comment: The div definition for 'Fusion_12345678' is empty. I am not using jquery. It seems document.getElementById cannot find the div printed from scriptlet

Comment: does the scriptlet run and load after your page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Access the `<div>` using `childNodes` on the parent div which is defined on the page:

```
document.getElementById("flash_chart").childNodes[1]
```